# CSS height property not working with h1 elements

Tags: html, css, height

**CSS FILE**

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: rgb(245, 82, 191);
}
.box1 {
  background-color: rgb(55, 39, 160);
}
.box2 {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
**HTML FILE**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles8.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boxes">
      <h1 class="box1">I'm with border-box and padding.</h1>
      <h1 class="box2">I'm normal.</h1>
      <h1 class="box3">I'm without border-box and with padding.</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Above I've mentioned the html file and also the CSS file which is linked to it. All the properties are properly followed but somehow the height property inside the div selector is not applied to any of the three of the elements. I've also tried assigning a class to the div element but it still did not work. I think the problem might be with the div selector because when I used the h1 selector and all the three classes box1, box2, box3 together in place of the div selector then it worked correctly and the height property was applied on all the three h1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  color: rgb(245, 82, 191);
}
h1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: rgb(55, 39, 160);
}
.box2 {
  background-color: firebrick;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
**HTML FILE**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles8.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boxes">
      <h1 class="box1">I'm with border-box and padding.</h1>
      <h1 class="box2">I'm normal.</h1>
      <h1 class="box3">I'm without border-box and with padding.</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should put the height and width on the element you want the height/width to be applied to, not to its parent.

Comment: Why not? Child elements inherit from parent elements. The color property was applied in the child elements.

Comment: They do no inherit the width/height properties, this is because the default height and width of these elements is 'auto' and not 'inherit'. hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Do you mean this?

```css
 div h1 {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      color: rgb(245, 82, 191);
    }
    .box1 {
      background-color: rgb(55, 39, 160);
    }
    .box2 {
      background-color: firebrick;
    }
    .box3 {
      background-color: goldenrod;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles8.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="boxes">
          <h1 class="box1">I'm with border-box and padding.</h1>
          <h1 class="box2">I'm normal.</h1>
          <h1 class="box3">I'm without border-box and with padding.</h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: applying it to the div is useless, they should just be applied to the h1's like in my answer

Comment: Oh wait im sorry, you didnt have a comma between the div and h1 in the css, excuse my illerate ass